# rotating a UIImageView in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

So I have the following code:

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

@implementation NewsFeedSubCell
@synthesize imageView_;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {


        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.size.width = 20;
        frame.size.height = 20;
        self.frame = frame;
        self.contentView.frame = frame;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.contentView.transform, degreesToRadians(90));
        [imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        self.imageView_ = imageView;
        [imageView release];



    }
    return self;
}
```

Any idea why this is not rotating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you taking the transform of the contentView? Try to use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` instead of `CGAffineTransformRotate`